# Determine if function was defined with "async"

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine if a function was defined using `async function` or `async (...) => ...` syntax?

I'm looking to implement the function `isDefinedWithAsync` where:

```
isDefinedWithAsync(async function() { return null; }) === true;
isDefinedWithAsync(function() { return null; }) === false;
isDefinedWithAsync(async () => null) === true;
isDefinedWithAsync(() => null) === false;
```

Is it possible to implement `isDefinedWithAsync`? And if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,

Straight from the [TC39 async/await Issues](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/78#issuecomment-164408675):

```
function isAsync(fn) {
   return fn.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction';
}
```

Here's a snippet that checks your 2 `async` samples above and a 3rd non-async function:

```js
function isAsync(fn) {
   return fn.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction';
}

// async functions
const foo = async () => { }
async function bar () { } 

// non-async function
function baz () { } 

console.log(isAsync(foo)) // logs true
console.log(isAsync(bar)) // logs true
console.log(isAsync(baz)) // logs false
```

But as mentioned in the rest of the comments on that issue, you shouldn't differentiate, at least conceptually, between [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)s and [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s since they behave the same.

Both can be `await`-ed/`then`-ed in the exact same way. An `async` marked function always implicitly returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to Nicholas' great answer:

If you want to avoid using string comparisons for type checks (due to the possibility of namespace collisions), you may be wanting to accomplish the same thing with instanceof:

```
function isAsync(fn) {
  return fn instanceof AsyncFunction;
}
```

In some environments you may get a `ReferenceError` that "AsyncFunction is not defined".

This error can be resolved as follows:

```
const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;

function isAsync(fn) {
  return fn instanceof AsyncFunction;
}
```

Now even a silly case like the following:

```
isAsyncFunction({ constructor: { name: 'AsyncFunction' } });
```

will correctly return `false`.