# Detect whether a function is async (using NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

This is a simple task in a web browser but in NodeJS it makes no distinction:

```
console.log({
  // 'Function' in browser, but empty string ('') in NodeJS
  '(() => {}).constructor.name': (() => {}).constructor.name,
  '(() => {}).__proto__.constructor.name': (async () => {}).__proto__.constructor.name,

  // 'AsyncFunction' in browser, but empty string ('') in NodeJS 
  '(async () => {}).constructor.name': (async () => {}).constructor.name,
  '(async () => {}).__proto__.constructor.name': (async () => {}).__proto__.constructor.name,
  
  // Evaluates to false in browser, but true in NodeJS
  '(async () => {}).constructor === (() => {}).constructor': (async () => {}).constructor === (() => {}).constructor,
  '(async () => {}).__proto__ === (() => {}).__proto__': (async () => {}).__proto__ === (() => {}).__proto__,
  '(async () => {}).__proto__.constructor === (() => {}).__proto__.constructor': (async () => {}).__proto__.constructor === (() => {}).__proto__.constructor,
});
```

The reason I want to distinguish this is so I can indiscriminately add wrapper code while maintaining the function's "signature". If I were to convert everything to just accept a `thenable` object via `Promise.resolve` then I would have to make most all function calls into async methods (or expecting an async `thenable`). This is a problem for nodejs (or React Native) as it exercises the **Promises/A+ specification**, so indiscriminately expecting everything to be async does change the functionality of the code.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or some kind of workaround in the meantime?

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using? Are you using a transpiler?

Comment: Don't use `.__proto__`, it's deprecated. Call `Object.getPrototypeOf()` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102413/determine-if-function-was-defined-with-async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060405/how-to-programmatically-find-if-a-function-is-async

Comment: Using Node.js v20.0.0 (and v18, v17, v16, v15, v11, and v10), I don't get the results you report above. I get `'Function'`, `'AsyncFunction'`, `'AsyncFunction'`, `false`, `false`, `false`. And that makes sense, since Node.js uses V8, the same JavaScript engine used in the Chromium browsers. I wouldn't expect V8 to work differently in this regard in a browser vs. Node.js. It sounds like you're transpiling or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if a function is async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508420/how-to-know-if-a-function-is-async)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I'm using v16.14.2 and running jest via npm script for React Native v0.71.7. It seems because I'm using TypeScript it's transpiling it in such a way that it won't distinguish between async and synchronous functions since it transpiles into the same thing.

Comment: @Steven - That will be the [`target` setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) in your `tsconfig.json`, it just be set to `"es5"`. For Node v16, you can at **least** use `"es2015"` (and probably more recent than that) so it doesn't convert `async` functions to state machines.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to distinguish this is so I can indiscriminately add wrapper code while maintaining the function's "signature"

Then you should not care whether the function was defined using `async`/`await` syntax or not.

You should care whether it returns a promise or not, when you call it. And [that's distinguishable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-promise) easily.

Comment: Due to transpilers (or compilers, I don't know what to call it) using Promises/A+ specification, it will break the current thread, which is undesirable when I want certain synchronous code to continue executing.

Comment: @Steven - It doesn't matter whether the function uses `async`/`await` or returns a promise (or some other thanable) some other way. What matters is just whether it returns a promise (well, a thenable). The link Bergi gives above does exactly what you've done in your answer -- looks for a `then` method.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary workaround is to test if the result is a `thenable` and return an asynchronous anonymous function awaiting on the result.

```
const debug = (message, fn) => {
  const reportError = (e, isSync) => {
    console.error(`${message}: ${e.message || e} (${isSync})`);
    throw e;
  };
  return (...args) => {
    try {
      // First, attempt to execute the provided function as if it is synchronous
      const result = fn?.(...args);

      // If its result is a thenable, then catch any errors while awaiting its response
      if (typeof result?.then === 'function') {
        return (async () => {
          try {
            return await result;
          }
          catch (e) { reportError(e, false); }
        })();
      }

      return result;
    }
    catch (e) { reportError(e, true); }
  };
};
```

It feels like it should be reducible further, but the result needs to be awaited on (I believe?) to be able to catch the rejected promise.

EDIT: Because I'm using TypeScript in my React Native project, it's transpiling the code such that the async functions appear just as synchronous ones do.

Comment: This is basically what Bergi was saying to do in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77493759/157247). He even points to a previous answer about how to detect a thenable.